# JS short params url

Tags: javascript, url

I need to load a pdf by some parameters, which are very long.

URL with parameter example:

`example?params=veryLongParams&anotherBigPArams&andTheBiggestParameter`

I want to shorten it to something like :

`example?params=123csdfskj1k23123jkjkbn12b31`

Is there a method to shorten my parameters with js?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, could you please explain more? You want to upload or download a PDF? Do you own the server?

Comment: and in addition to @sjahan's questions - who defined these long parameters and their capturing logic on the server side?

Comment: The parameters are dependant on the serverside - if those are the only ones that the server accepts, and you cannot change it - there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I'm guessing he's using an online PDF content generator, unless the OP gives us more to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, not via GET if the URL is too long. [How long is too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/344029)

However, the HTTP spec specifies no size limit for POST requests. If the server also accepts POST requests for the same URL endpoint (usually the norm) the following would work (if you or something else can create them):

[POST Method Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#Example) (MDN Docs)

> A simple form using the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type:
>
> ```
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: foo.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 61
>
> params=veryLongParams&anotherBigPArams&andTheBiggestParameter
> ```

But depending on what creates the URL, this can be done for you. i.e. an HTML form by specifying `method="post"`.

[Sending form data via POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_POST_method) (MDN Docs):

```html
<form action="http://foo.com" method="post">
    <input name="params" value="veryLongParams">
    <input name="anotherBigPArams" value="">
    <input name="andTheBiggestParameter" value="">

    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```